# How can I make a link_to remote link pull up a jQuery dialog in Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my view that I want to add the link, I have:

```
= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path( :format => js), :remote => :true
#edit-dialog
```

My controller action is empty.
My edit.js.erb looks like:

```
$("#edit-dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  width: auto,
  open: function() {
    $("edit-dialog").html(<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>")
  }
});
```

When I click the link, I get the Javascript rendered as text in a new page.

```
$("edit-dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  width: auto,
  open: function() {
    $("edit-dialog").html(<the partial contents are loaded here>)
  }
});
```

Why isn't the js getting executed. Instead it is getting returned as text and being rendered into a separate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not have jquery_ujs in may application.js. I changed it to include:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_ui
```

It now works.